# Set restriction for the datetime-local , only selecting the current date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetime

I am now writing a form that will include the date picker .. and I'm trying to use the  element. for now, I would like to restrict it to only select the current date.

for example
today is July 7

so the selection on the date picker will be only July 7

Can someone help me with it? I'm new at web application

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check in</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="datefield">
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check Out</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="CheckOut">
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show any research you have done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. For instance, `input` elements have `min` and `max` attributes that tell the control what the minimum and maximum values are. How do you think those could apply to your situation?

Comment: See [MDN: *Input type datetime-local*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local). Set the *min* and *max* attributes to appropriate values like `...min="2021-07-04T00:00" max="2021-07-04T23:59:59"...` to restrict selections to some time on 4 July 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check in</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="CheckIn" min="2021-07-07T00:00" max="2021-07-07T23:59" >
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check Out</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="CheckOut" min="2021-07-07T00:00" max="2021-07-07T23:59">
</div>
```

OR, if you want it for "the current day" you will need some Javascript:

```js
const today=(new Date()).toLocaleString("EN-CA").slice(0,10); // get local current date
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="datetime-local"]').forEach(el=>{
 el.min=today+"T00:00"; el.max=today+"T23:59";
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check in</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="CheckIn">
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="font-weight-bold">Check Out</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="CheckOut">
</div>
```

I am using `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()` here instead of `Date.prototype.toISOString()` as this will return the *locale* date and not the GMT date, which might differ at certain times of the day, depending on which time zone the user is in. The locale "EN-CA" ensures the "YYYY-MM-DD" format.